Having Spyder in different environments open differently
I want to have different instances for spyder for different environment. I can uncheck use a single instance in Tools>>Preferences>>Application>>Advanced settings. But I want spyder from different environments to open differently. Like for an example I want that my spyder in env1 should have files file1 and file2 open while spyder from env2 should have files file3 and file4 open when I start them. Whenever I start spyder it always has the same files open, no matter whatever environment I choose. Is it possible to do so?
I could not find any ways to change environment variables and change default cache location for spyder in different environments, so that spyder might open differently for that environment. There is no such functionality in anaconda as well. The developer here says "it will be improved in future versions of spyder" but I couldn't find any solutions.
